# OxyPlot legend items managing

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

is there any way to manage items in legend? I mean e.q. remove some items from legend but not from whole plot? I know that each serie in plot is linked with one item in legend, but i want to break this rule and put to legend only selected series.

Thanks for your request.

Comment: If you does not assign a tittle to the series(lineseries, etc), it is not represented on the legend.

Comment: Ah, that´s a good idea! Thanks a lot, i will try it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't assign a title to the series (`LineSeries`, etc), it won't be represented on the legend:

```
var plotModel = new PlotModel();
plotModel.LegendTitle = "Legend";
plotModel.LegendPosition = LegendPosition.RightBottom;

plotModel.Series.Add(new LineSeries
{
    ItemsSource = someItemSource,
    Color = OxyColors.Red,
    //Title = "title" <- Title commented
});
```

---

Starting v2.0.1, the legend doesn't automatically appear and all `PlotModel.LegendXxx` members have been removed. You now have to manually add one legend:

```
var plotModel = new PlotModel();
plotModel.Legends.Add(new Legend() { 
    LegendTitle = "Legend",
    LegendPosition = LegendPosition.RightBottom,
});

plotModel.Series.Add(new LineSeries
{
    ItemsSource = someItemSource,
    Color = OxyColors.Red,
    //Title = "title" <- Title commented
});
```

Comment: `Series` also has a `bool` called `RenderInLegend` that you can use to hide the series in the legend.